# How to change font in html button for a character

Tags: html, css, fonts

I don't know if this is possible, what I am looking for is a way to change a specific character font, for example, I want to make this button:

[image]

the text has "calibri" font in css, something like this:

```
input[type="button"]{
  font-family: calibri;
}
```

And I need to use "icomoon" font for the last character, so my HTML should look like this:

```
<input type='button' value="Move to right <span class=icomoon>x</span>" />
```

But I think this is not possible, other ways could be using soms CSS pseudos like  ::after or :first-letter, but I can not figure them out.

So, the question is: It is possible to change the last character of a HTML button using css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inserting a span inside the value of an input, you can just use a button element,

```
<style>
    .button {
        font-family: "OriginalFont";
    }
    .icomoon {
        font-family: "icomoon"!important;
    }
</style>

<button class="button">
    Move to Right <span class="icomoon">x</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple `font-family` then consider using the code of the icon you want to use.

Here is an idea using `font-awesome`:

```css
input[type="button"]{
  font-family: calibri,'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
<input type='button' value="Move to right &#xf35a;" >
```

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work for me, because the symbol I am using is also a calibri letter, so it appears as calibri font. This answer is a good idea and works for "non-calibri" characters only (or any previous fonts in the font-family list).